# Conflictuos input from a leetcode problem about LRU cache

Tags: java, caching, lru

I'm trying to solve this question from LeetCode (https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/description/) but I'm finding an issue with a specific input. I'm using their forum as well, but they take too long to reply.

I would like to know why the final output for this entry ["LRUCache","put","put","get","put","put","get"]
[[2],[2,1],[2,2],[2],[1,1],[4,1],[2]] is (-1) instead of 2.

As far as I know, the end configuration of the cache would be [(4,1), (2,2)), then 2 would be returned, not -1.

Thank you!

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public class LRUCache {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> keyToArrayPosition = new HashMap<>();
    Tuple [] cache;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int capacity;

    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        cache = new Tuple[this.capacity];
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
    }

    public int get(int key) 
    {    
        if(keyToArrayPosition.keySet().contains(key))
        {
            int position = keyToArrayPosition.get(key);
            Tuple t = cache[position];
            return t.value;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) 
    {
        Tuple t = new Tuple(key, value);
        //set
        if(keyToArrayPosition.keySet().contains(key))
        {
            int position = keyToArrayPosition.get(key);
            cache[position] = t;
            return;
        }

        if(tail <= capacity - 1)
        { 
            cache[tail] = t;
            keyToArrayPosition.put(key, tail);
            tail++;
        }
        else
        {
            tail--;
            keyToArrayPosition.remove(cache[cache.length - 1].key);
            for(int i = tail; i > 0; i--)
            {
                cache[i] = cache[i - 1];
                keyToArrayPosition.put(cache[i].key, i);
            }
            cache[0] = t;
            keyToArrayPosition.put(key, 0);
            tail++;
        }
    }
}

class Tuple
{
   public int key;
   public int value;

    public Tuple(int key, int value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

/**
 * Your LRUCache object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * LRUCache obj = new LRUCache(capacity);
 * int param_1 = obj.get(key);
 * obj.put(key,value);
 */
```

Comment: I think `LinkedHashMap` would be a good implementation of `LRU` cache.you can try it.

Comment: I'll definitely try, but my main concern is the result of that input. I don't think so it is correct. Do you agree? Otherwise, what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: the end configuration of the cache would be [(4,1), (1,1)] not [(4,1), (2,2)] .because you are implementing the LRU not LFU

Comment: @Cherokee - It makes sense, but it doesn't work for the case base -> ["LRUCache","put","put","get","put","get","put","get","get","get"] [[2],[1,1],[2,2],[1],[3,3],[2],[4,4],[1],[3],[4]]